# Return SUM of meta_value based on post_id

Tags: php, select

I am trying to show the sum of `meta_value` (which is numeric) for all the instances where `post_id` is the same in table `postmeta`.  From looking at other replies the following seems to be what should do this but I just get nothing returned

```
<?php     
    global $wpdb;

    $data = $wpdb->query("
        SELECT SUM(meta_value)
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE `post_id` = $post_id
                ");
    echo $data;
  ?>
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with this when compared to other answers.  Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you're using globals. That's the first step to Cthulhu.

Comment: What is $wpdb? is id a PDO object or your own DAL? Also: try to echo the resulting query to better see any error...

Comment: `$wpdb` is the database object of WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

Well... Are you connected to the database?  And when you're including object properties inside a string, it's good form to encase them in braces, like so:

```
$data = $wpdb->query("SELECT SUM(meta_value)
                      FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
                      WHERE `post_id` = $post_id
                     ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your php variables if they are complex, so:

```
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
```

Answer (score 0):

For SELECTing, you should use `$wpdb->get_results()` instead of `$wpdb->query()`.

`$wpdb->query()` "… returns an integer corresponding to the number of rows affected/selected."

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have changed the code to reflect the above including he encapsulation and using `get_results` instead of `query` but now just get 'Array' as the returned result.

```
        global $wpdb;

$data = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT SUM($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
        WHERE `post_id` = the_id()
                ");
    echo $data;
```

Do I need to use a `foreach()` loop to cycle the resultant array? I have also checked there is data and also that `the_id()` is valid